# How to construct dynamic query in LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

The users type in a textbox, keywords to look for in a travel destination. Sometimes, they just type "hot", sometimes "hot humid stormy", etc.

This code works for a single keyword:

```
where d.Element("Description").Value.Contains(textBox1.Text)
```

How do I revise the code to build the query so that it works for any number of keywords? Note that all the keywords typed in the textbox must match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you mean to search if any of the entries applies:

```
where textBox1.Text.Split(' ').All(t => d.Element("Description").Value.Contains(t))
```

Comment: I am looking for ALL of keywords, not ANY. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

First I'd define a `ContainAny` extension method for `String` to encapsulate looking for multiple values in a `String`

```
public static bool ContainsAny(this string source, IEnumerable<string> values) {
  foreach (var cur in values) {
    if (source.Contains(cur)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Then you can use the `String.Split` method to break up the words in `textBox1.Text` and feed it to `ContainsAny`

```
where d.Element("Description").Value.ContainsAny(textBox1.Text.Split(' '));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var keywords = textBox1.Text.Split(' ');
//-------
.Where(e => keywords.All(w => d.Element("Description").Value.Contains(w)))
```

You can use `All` or `Any` method. It depends on your needs.